# Openfire, Spark, настройка группы пользователей

Tags: xmpp, spark, openfire

появилась необходимость в локальной сети небольшого офиса поднять чат, выбор пал на Openfire и клиент spark, базу данных использовал встроенную, проблема в том что не могу настроить отображение пользователей в группе, т.е что бы с пк работников нельзя было писать друг другу а только мне, но я видел всех и мог писать всем[image: введите сюда описание изображения]